# Probability metric (or distance) that "detects" type of distribution

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, probability-theory, metric-spaces

I am interested if there exists a metric (or distance) between two probability distribution $P$ and $Q$ such that:

> If $P$ is a discrete probability distribution then $d(P,Q)<\infty$ 
>   iff $Q$ is also discrete (not necessarily on the same support), and if  $d(P,Q)=\infty$  the $Q$ is not discrete.

Note that Kullback–Leibler divergence almost has this property, since if $P$ and $Q$ are mutually singular than $d(P,Q)=\infty$.  The problem is that if $P$ and $Q$ are discrete but defined on different supports than we also have $d(P,Q)=\infty$.

Note that we also want a metric such that for convergence in this metric would imply convergence in distribution.

Note that as long as we can find a distance that in some way 'detects' that the distribution is discrete then we can relax  $d(P,Q)=\infty$ if $Q$ is not discrete.

Thank you

Comment: I assume you mean an "interesting" metric, but I'm not sure what notion of "interesting" you necessarily want. Still, you should note that one can of course trivially construct a "boring" metric with $d(P,Q)=1$ if $P,Q$ are discrete and distinct and $d(P,Q)=\infty$ if not both of $P$ and $Q$ are discrete and the two are distinct.

Comment: @Ian. Agree. It has to be meaningful.

Comment: But what's "meaningful"? Is it enough for convergence in this metric to imply convergence in distribution?

Comment: @Ian Yes, sorry for not being clear. Yes, we want convergence in this metric to imply convergence in distribution.

Comment: @Ian I am curries what would be an example of a trivial metric?

Comment: I gave one in my first comment. In fact convergence in that metric rather vacuously implies convergence in distribution, but it's not a "useful" metric.

Comment: @ I see. Any idea what useful metric might qualify?

Comment: See unfortunately most of the metrics I know about, e.g. the Wasserstein metric, want to quantify the idea that a discrete distribution can be close to a continuous distribution. For example, in a sense Binomial(10000,1/2) is very similar to Normal(5000,2500). Tweaking such a thing to satisfy your criterion (e.g. by moving non-discrete distributions to be infinitely far away from anything other than themselves) gives an incomplete metric space, which is bad for certain purposes.

Comment: @Ian what about distance like Kullback-Liebler?

Comment: 1. It's not a metric. 2. It is not clear how to extend it to the case where $P$ is not absolutely continuous with respect to $Q$

Comment: You could come up with something along the lines of $$d(P,Q) = \sup_{n\in\mathbb{N}} \sup_{X\subseteq \mathbb{R}: \lvert X\rvert = n} \lvert P(X)-Q(X)\rvert.$$ This will be $0$ if both $P,Q$ are discrete, and strictly positive if at least one isn't. (With the value depending on whatever atoms the non-discrete one has, if it's not absolutely continuous).

Comment: Maybe you can use the discrete Wasserstein metric. If $P = \sum_{j=1}^{k_1} p_j \delta_{\theta_j}, Q = \sum_{j=1}^{k_2} q_j \delta_{\phi_j}$, then $$ d_1(Q,P) = \inf_q \sum_{i,j} t_{i,j} |\theta_i - \phi_j|, $$ where the infimum is over all joint probability distributions on $[1, \dots, k_1] \times [1,\dots, k_2]$ such that $\sum_j t_{i,j} = p_i$, and $\sum_i t_{i,j} = q_i$. See the paper "Wasserstein distances for discrete measures and
convergence in nonparametric mixture models" by XuanLong Nguyen for more info.

Comment: @ClementC. Very interesting. Is this something known or used?

Comment: Not that i know of.

Comment: @sometempname but how will it tell me if $P$ is discrete that $Q$ is or not discrete?

Comment: Not sure if I understand the question. If $Q$ is not discrete you set $d_1(P,Q)=\infty$.

Comment: @sometempname y Suppose, for some reason, we don't know that $Q$ is discrete or not. What we want is to have a distance that will tell you if $Q$ is discrete or not. This is what the metric of ClementC. does

Comment: I don't think you have to compare measures in order to find that $Q$ is discrete.

Comment: @sometempname how else can we do it?

Comment: Maybe compute something similar to @ClementC suggestion, such as $\sup_{n\in\mathbb{N}} \sup_{X\subset\mathbb{R} : |X| =n} P(X)$, and check if it's $1$ or smaller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Ported from a comment of mine above:*

You could come up with something along the lines of
$$
d(P,Q) \stackrel{\rm def}{=} \sup_{n\in\mathbb{N}} \sup_{X\subseteq \mathbb{R}: \lvert X\rvert = n} \lvert P(X)-Q(X)\rvert.$$
This will be $0$ if both $P,Q$ are discrete, and strictly positive if at least one is not. *(With the value depending on whatever atoms the non-discrete one has, if it's not absolutely continuous.)*

This does not *quite* meet the requirement $<\infty$ vs. $\infty$, but does something qualitatively similar.

Comment: Indeed, thank you. We can define a new distance given by $ |log d(P,Q)|$ if we ant to meet the requirement of $\infty$.  However, I was after something that in some way 'detects' if the probability is discrete or not and this norm does it. Let me know if you think of some more.

Comment: I'll try to think a bit more about this.